# Java Swing application design in a way to create multiple instances of application by creating all objects only once

Tags: java, design-patterns, swing

We have a one Java Swing app. Now there is one requirement that it should be created in multiple desktops in one machine/computer. So its like creating different instances of main Java Swing app into different desktops/monitors with same CPU/machine just like in linux we can have different desktop in one OS at the same time.

Design constraints:

We need to create only one app instance and we need to utilize/store all objects of this app and use them to create different instance of main app

its looks we need to create a pool of objects of main swing app and use them to create others but is it correct way? Is there any other efficient way to achieve it?

This is kind of design question for creating new Java swing app for different desktops.

Comment: What do you mean by "different desktops"?  A separate computer?  A different user logon?

Comment: Its different desktop with same CPU

Comment: no same computer with different desktops same as in linux we can have different desktop in same machine/OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Builder pattern here , I think.Based on the requirement it will render different desktop UI components (set of features), if the features are not dynamic in nature.